# what does references.d.ts file do and where is it located in a NativeScript Project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

i am following [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/03/implement-a-barcode-scanner-using-telerik-nativescript/) in nativescript and it states to put

`/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/barcodescanner.d.ts" /> Needed for autocompletion and compilation.`

in  **references.d.ts** . my question is what does this file do and where is it located in a nativescript application

Comment: *.d.ts files are typescript declarations that allow you to use pure javascript libraries in typescript (e.g jQuery), without having to convert them into type-safe code.   The main references.d.ts file is picked up by the tscompiler and usually references all other d.ts files.  Depending on config the references.d.ts file is _usually_ in the project root.    [CodePlex](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Writing%20Definition%20%28.d.ts%29%20Files) have a good basic intro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference.d.ts file can be added to your project in the root directory, prior to NativeScript 3.0+ it was included in typescript and angular template projects. It is used to add external type definitions to your project such as `tns-platform-declarations`. I believe however since that tutorial is a year old you won't need to add the `reference.d.ts` file to import those anymore and the typescript compiler should pull them in automatically.

Comment: i cant see reference.d.ts file in my root so i create myself one. and add *.d.ts files from nativescript-barcodescanner plugin that includes `/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/barcodescanner.android.d.ts" /> Needed for autocompletion and compilation.
/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-barcodescanner/barcodescanner.common.d.ts" /> Needed for autocompletion and compilation.` but in my main.ts file the project cant see module property and it says it does not exist

Comment: in my main.ts file i have `import barcodescannerModule = require("nativescript-barcodescanner");` but it cant recognize module property e.g `barcodescannerModule.available()` "available" does not exist

Comment: instead of using require you may want to try using `import * as barcodeScanner from 'nativescript-barcodescanner';`

Comment: i must do something like this  `import {BarcodeScanner} from 'nativescript-barcodescanner';
 var barcodescannerModule=new BarcodeScanner;` that "BarcodeScanner" is a class in BarcodeScanner file that is exported.